# Use iOS 8 network extension to install signed VPN profiles programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, vpn

Based on this [tutorial](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) and apple's new **network extension** framework for iOS 8 I developed a small vpn application that is able to install, remove, connect and disconnect vpn profiles. Unfortunately this tutorial deals only with unsigned vpn profiles. Also, apple didn't publish any documentation so far and refers to the framework's header files where I couldn't find anything about signed vpn profiles. I wonder if there is a way at all. Does anybody know if and how this can be achieved?

I checked the following header files for hints on this topic:

```
NetworkExtension/NEVPNManager.h
NetworkExtension/NEVPNConnection.h
NetworkExtension/NEVPNProtocol.h
NetworkExtension/NEVPNProtocolIPSec.h
```

Comment: could it be possible to access already installed and signed vpn profiles through the network extension api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Network Extension framework in iOS 8 creates profiles that are unsigned and there is no option currently to get the profiles to show as signed/verified.  Would definitely write a bug report against Apple about this.

Answer (score 3):

in iOS 9 user doesn't have this view. User will see only request to add VPN configuration profile to settings. [image]

Comment: I'm developing a VPN application, I would like to ask how you can add VPN and display this Alert. I researched for a long time, but did not progress, hoping to get your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Vincent, system automatically will raise this alert when you'll try to save your VPN configuration using NetworkExtension method saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:. It's similar to request access to location from user. Also this alert will be shown only for iOS 9, iOS 8 uses old system of redirection to preferences.app

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I would like to know which class method? NEFilterManager or NEVPNManager. It seems to need an entitlement file from `networkextension@apple.com` to use these API, right?

Comment: It's NEVPNManager class. You can work with NEVPNManager without additional entitlement(don't forget to setup provisioning profile on developer's portal). But for NEFilterManager you need that entitlement.